# how to show product in tabular format in MVC 4.0 (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Currently my data is showing in row like this

Item 1  Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5

I get this result using the following code

```
@using SportsStore.Models.WebUI
@model SportsStore.Models.ProductsListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}
<div style="padding-left: 300px;">
    <table style="height: 300px; border: 2px; border: 1px solid Red;">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var p in Model.Products)
            {

                <td style="height: 100px; width: 150px; border: 2px">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product",
        new { id = p.ProductID })">
                        <img alt="@p.ProductDescription" src="@p.Imagename"  width="150" height="150"/>
                        <br />
                        Name : @p.ProductDescription<br />
                        Price : <span>@p.RetailPrice</span> </a>
                </td>


            }
        </tr>
    </table



</div>
```

**I want to show my data like**

Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5

Item 6 Item 7 Item 8 Item 9 Item 10

Please Help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: show it in divs not table.

Comment: Hi can you guide me more about it ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use divs. First set a `width` size for outher div, and set `width` size cell divs and `float:left` like following.

```
<div style="padding-left: 300px;width:750px;">
    @foreach (var p in Model.Products)
    {
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 150px; float:left;">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product",
    new { id = p.ProductID })">
                <img alt="@p.ProductDescription" src="@p.Imagename"  width="150" height="150"/>
                <br />
                Name : @p.ProductDescription<br />
                Price : <span>@p.RetailPrice</span> </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

so, if your outher div `width = 750` and cell divs `width = 150` then you have 750/150 = 5 columns. so, its automaticly create 5 columns in per row.